# JS: set active class only on current element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set *active* class only to current button, but I can't seem to remove it when another button is clicked.

I created a Loop to identify which button is clicked, but I couldn't manage to remove class from other ones

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('provas-card-btn')

for(var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
btn[i].classList.remove('active')
  btn[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    this.classList.add('active');
  });
  ;
}
```

```css
body{
  background:#2a2a2a;
}

.provas-card-btn{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:100px;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  background:transparent;
  position:relative;
  transition: all .3s;
  margin:20px;
  }
  
  .provas-card-btn:after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:2px;
    width:18px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:calc(50% - 9px);
    top:13px;
  }
  .provas-card-btn:before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:18px;
    width:2px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:calc(50% - 1px);
    top:5px;
  }
  
.provas-card-btn.active:before{

    transform:rotate(90deg);
  }

}
```

```html
<button class="provas-card-btn"></button>
<button class="provas-card-btn"></button>
<button class="provas-card-btn"></button>
<button class="provas-card-btn"></button>
```

I'm yet a noob in Js, so if anyone could help me I'll be grateful!
Also, I'm trying to use pure js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listener needs to loop through all the buttons, removing the class from all but `this`.

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('provas-card-btn')

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < btn.length; j++) {
      if (btn[j] == this) {
        btn[j].classList.add('active');
      } else {
        btn[j].classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #2a2a2a;
}

.provas-card-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s;
  margin: 20px;
}

.provas-card-btn:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 9px);
  top: 13px;
}

.provas-card-btn:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 18px;
  width: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  top: 5px;
}

.provas-card-btn.active:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


}
```

```html
<button class="provas-card-btn"></button>
<button class="provas-card-btn"></button>
<button class="provas-card-btn"></button>
<button class="provas-card-btn"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just had to change `if (btn[j] == this) {
        this.classList.add`

Comment: Isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: Oops, I had an `i` that should be `j` in the `for()` header.

Comment: there's a mistake here `for (var j = 0; i < btn.length; j++`
but I figured out and it's running now, thanks to you!